# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not "list" : Django save model

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to save a model but am unable to because of a `TypeError` I am being given.

I have looked at other answers with similar errors but they are different problems.

```py
now = dateTime.now()
miliTime = int(str(now.hour) + str(now.minute)
timeConvert = miliTime - 1200
timeString = str(timeConvert)
standard_t = timeString[:1] + ":" + timeString[1:]
standardTime = standard_t + " " + p

time_1 = standard_time
time_2 = standard_time

user = StaffMember.objects.get(id = request.session['client']['id'])
userPunchCard = PunchCard.objects.get(employee = StaffMember.objects.get(name = user.name))

punch = []
try: 
  if len(userPunchCard.time.punch) < 2:
    punch.append(time_2)
    userPunchCard.time = punch
    userPunchCard.save()
except:
  punch.append(time_1)
  userPunchCard.time = punch
  userPunchCard.save()
```

The main issue is trying to save the `array`. The `try` and `except` is to check for a `punch` if present.

Here's the full error message

```
TypeError: int() argument must be string, a bytes-like object or a number, not a 'list'.
```

Comment: The error is telling you that the list `punch` is not compatible with the data type for the `time` field in your model. Please update your question with the model for `userPunchCard`. If it is DateTime, then it should be a DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, my model for time was only accepting an int object and the whole time I was forcing a string into it. I had to change the integerField to a CharField in my models file for time.